# Searching for a string in workbook A, while this string is part of a larger string in Workbook B

Tags: vba, excel, macros

This is a question about a Macro in Excel:

I am working with 2 workbooks. Workbook A is full of strings of the following form:

```
"x ind. y"
```

where the x and y indicate certain arbitrary strings, with the string "ind." in between them. Let's say that a one such particular string in which I am interested finds itself in cell B2.

Now I want to extract x which is the substring until the "ind" substring. I can do this with the following formula:

```
=left(B2,search(""ind"",B2)-1)
```

This formula has proven itself to work just fine, so there isn't the problem. 
My question is, how can I assign the result of this formula to a string in my macro? And then if I have this string I want to search for it in workbook B.

I can't use something like this:

```
dim word as string
...
word = "=left(B2,search(""ind"",B2)-1)"
```

or

```
word.formula = "=left(B2,search(""ind"",B2)-1)"
```

I could do `Range("some cell").Formula = "=left(B2,search(""ind"",B2)-1)"` but that would paste the result of the formula in some cell, but this is not what I want, I just want to have it stored in the string 'word'.

Comment: left(range("b2").value,worksheetfunction.search(""ind"",range("b2").value) something like this

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a space between "x" and "ind.", try this:

`word = Left(wbA.Range("B2").Value, InStr(wbA.Range("B2").Value, "ind.") - 2)`

Where `wbA` is a reference to your Workbook A.